# Getting "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: GEOS is required and has not been detected." although GEOS is installed

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-14.04, geodjango, geos

I'm running *Django 1.8* and *Python 3.4* on *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*. Just recently, my Django app has been reporting that **GEOS** is not present. **GEOS** is installed and **libgeos_c.so** is where it's supposed to be (*/usr/lib/*). My code seems fine. It is the source of a docker image which still works. This seems to indicate an os/incompatibility issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

The full traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2358, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1778, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "<path/to/my/pycharm/project>/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    "See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/%s/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/" % get_docs_version())
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: GEOS is required and has not been detected. Are you sure it is installed? See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/
```

I've tried reinstalling **libgdal-dev**. All relevant packages (GDAL, GEOS etc) are up to date.

I've tried working my way back through the Python code. it fails in **djanjo/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py** on the following. As HAS_GEOS is set to false it reports that GEOS is not present.

```
try:
    from .libgeos import geos_version, geos_version_info  # NOQA: flake8 detects only the last __all__
    HAS_GEOS = True
    __all__ += ['geos_version', 'geos_version_info']
except ImportError:
    HAS_GEOS = False
```

I suspect that a recent OS upgrade/patch has broken GEOS or GDAL. The root cause seems to be something to do with **ctypes**, but I can't see what it could be.

The following might be useful.

```
>>> from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceback_Add


>>> from django.contrib.gis import gdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver  # NOQA
  File "/<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/<path/to/my/virtualenv>/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ctypes import c_void_p
  File "/<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
  File "/<path/to/my/homedir>/pycharm-4.5.1/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceback_Add
```

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem today, though in an unrelated python project. This is is the line I also encountered and which led me here:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceback_Add
```

It looks like Ubunut has pushed a Python 3.4 update which is not compatible with existing virtual environments. I'm able to fix the problem by recreating the virtualenv. Where this was impractical for the moment I simply replaced the virtualenv's python with the system one:

```
cd my-virtualenv
cp /usr/bin/python3.4 bin/python3.4
```

I can't say if this is a very *sane* thing to do, but it does seem to work in my case.

Comment: Tried creating new _virtualenv_ with same requirements.txt as old. Still got the same error. Tried replacing virtualenv's python with `/usr/bin/python3.4`. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Replacing the python3 excecutable did the trick. Too lazy to re-create my virtualenv. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
cp /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/my-virtualenv/bin/python3
```

instead, because that's the actual non-symlink file.

Comment: `python3` links to `python3.4`. See attached snippet from `ls` command. 

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Jun  3 16:34 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4`

`-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 3697592 Jul 28 20:56 /usr/bin/python3.4`